# Sending XML and getting error http 415 unsupported media type

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-7.0

I have a problem with sending XML format to by endpoint in my ASP.NET Core 7 Web API project.

My controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Consumes("application/xml")]
    [Route("processXml")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ProcessXml([FromBody] PersonModel person)
    {
        // Your action logic
        return Ok();
    }
```

My `PersonModel`

```
[XmlRoot("Person")]
public class PersonModel
{
    [XmlAttribute("Id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("FirstName")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("LastName")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

What I'm trying to send by Postman

```
<Person Id="1">
    <FirstName>John</firstName>
    <LastName>Doe</lastName>
</Person>
```

Everything looks fine to me.

Of course I have `content-type: application/xml` but in the result I get `415 Unsupported Media Type`.

I really can't figure out what's wrong with that.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you are missing

```
services.AddControllers().AddXmlDataContractSerializerFormatters();
```

in startup.cs, look at https://peterdaugaardrasmussen.com/2020/11/28/asp-net-core-set-up-a-controller-endpoint-to-receive-xml-instead-of-json/

Comment: I added this, but now there is a weird response : 
"person": [
            "The person field is required."
        ]

Even swagger giving me this Request body:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PersonModel>
 <id>0</id>
 <firstName>string</firstName>
 <lastName>string</lastName>
</PersonModel>

I dont know why there is no XmlAttribute element in PersonModel.

Answer (score 0):

Solution I found, but I'm not satisfied with that. Can I do this by passing it in method parameter?

```
[HttpPost]
[Consumes("application/xml")]
[Route("processXml")]
public async Task<IActionResult> ProcessXml()
{
    try
    {
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Request.Body))
        {
            string xmlString = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(PersonModel));

            using (StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(xmlString))
            {
                PersonModel person = (PersonModel)serializer.Deserialize(stringReader);
            }

            return Ok("XML processed successfully");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return BadRequest($"Error processing XML: {ex.Message}");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't ask a question in your answer - ask a new question. And you know you can self-accept an answer right?

Answer (score 0):

There's a case mismatch in the XML tags for `FirstName` and `LastName`. XML is case-sensitive, so you need to make sure the tags in the XML match the property names in your class. The correct xml should be:

```
<Person Id="1">
    <FirstName>John</FirstName>
    <LastName>Doe</LastName>
</Person>
```

To configure XML formatters implemented using `XmlSerializer`, call `AddXmlSerializerFormatters` in Program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddXmlSerializerFormatters();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd just created a new web api, and had this issue, I was just missing reference to

```
System.Text.Encodings.Web
```

Then my request using the controller that was set to consume XML as yours is, allowed me to pass the XML string from the default Swashbuckle Swagger and it deserialised itself; i.e.,

```
public IActionResult CheckRequest(myRequest request)
```